# How to reset Google Cloud Shell environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-shell

I am trying to reset my Cloud Shell disk. I am deleting projects and creating new, but getting same cloud shell with all pre-installed files. Is there anyway to reset completely.

Comment: There is no procedure to do this but the approach taken in this post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067968/how-to-reset-google-cloud-shell-user-persistent-disk?rq=1

Comment: @jarmod, I tried that already, unfortunately no reply from support

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset Google Cloud Shell user persistent disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067968/how-to-reset-google-cloud-shell-user-persistent-disk)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get a completely new instance of Google Cloud Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709859/is-it-possible-to-get-a-completely-new-instance-of-google-cloud-shell)

Answer (score 12):

Yes there is

```
Restore your Cloud Shell home directory to a clean state:

Check for personal files in the home directory:
  ls -a $HOME
Remove all files from your home directory:
  sudo rm -rf $HOME
In the Cloud Shell menu, click the gear icon, then click Restart Cloud Shell. Click Restart Cloud Shell in the confirmation dialog.
```

From the docs https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/resetting-cloud-shell

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to manually reset the cloud shell. According to the documentation, the cloud shell VM is terminated after one hour of inactivity. You might want to kill your session for that to take effect :

[Cloud Shell Doc](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features)

But keep in mind that the cloud shell is not meant to be a full blown machine. It's more for testing and launching ad-hoc gcloud and gsutil commands.

So it's better to spin up a new Cloud Compute instance for your development purposes, instead of using the cloud Shell.